# How to build a Laravel query with joins and sum?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to configure a query within a Laravel app that is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT SUM(balance), name FROM db.statement_versions
INNER JOIN statements ON statement_versions.statement_id = statements.id
INNER JOIN accounts ON statements.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY name;
```

This query works when I run it in MySQL Workbench, but when I try to translate it into PHP with the Laravel query builder I am getting an error. What I ultimately want is to return all `accounts` with their summed balance of `statement_versions.balance`. Here is my code right now:

```
public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
        $query->select('accounts.name')->sum('statement_versions.balance')
            ->join('statements', 'statement_versions.statement_id', '=', 'statements.id')
            ->join('accounts', 'statements.account_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
            ->orderBy('balance', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('statement_versions.balance', 'accounts.name')
    ));
}
```

I have tried a couple different variations of this, but I get the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'statement_versions.balance' in 'field list'`. How can I solve this and get the query working correctly?

Comment: What is `$query`? Post your complete code

Comment: @Paras I've updated the post with the complete code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Not having your tables it will be a bit hard, but I hope that this will give you a path to what you want to achieve, it might be luck that it will work from the first shot :)

```
DB::table('statement_versions as sv')
  ->select([
    'name',
    DB::raw('sum(balance) as total')
  ])
  ->join('statements as s', 'sv.statement_id', '=', 's.id')
  ->join('accounts as a', 's.account_id', '=', 'a.id')
  ->groupBy('name');
```